# How can I show the equality of integration for shifting simple functions over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\phi(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_i\chi_{E_i}(x)$ be a simple function on $\mathbb{R}$ with finite support. I want to show that 
\begin{equation}
\int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x+t).
\end{equation}
It seems rather obvious, since 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n a_i \cdot m(E_i) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_i \cdot m(E_i + t)
\end{equation}
and furthermore, 
\begin{equation}
m(supp\{x : \phi(x) > 0\}) = m(supp\{x : \phi(x+t) > 0\})
\end{equation}
but I am unsure if this is enough to prove my desired statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I think that it is enough to show that the *Lebesgue measure* is invariant for "translations of the sets".

Comment: We are given that in Royden's Real Analysis as a proposition or theorem.

Comment: Then you are right. Another idea is to put $x+t=s$ and do a substitution.